# Reactjs why mongodb default value is not showing in placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V79KK.png)
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCtac.png)

i wanted to update user details and the old or default values should placeholder and
i'm building simple user application form but the user update is not working
**is that problem with frontend or backend**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import React from 'react';


function UpdateUser(){
    const location = useLocation();
    const [fname, setFname] = useState("");
    const [lname, setLname] = useState(""); 
    const [rnum, setRnum] = useState(""); 



        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(location);
            setFname(location.state.fname);
            setLname(location.state.lname);
            setRnum(location.state.rnum);
        }, [])

        const updateData = () => {
            console.log(fname, lname);
            fetch("http://localhost:5000/updateUser", {
      method: "POST",
      crossDomain: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
       id:location.state._id,
       fname: fname,
       lname: lname
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
          window.location.href = "./userDetails";
      });
        }
    return (
        <div className="auth-wrapper">
            <div className="auth-inner">

               First Name<br/>
               <input placeholder="First Name" className="form-control" defaultValue={fname} 
               onChange={(e) => setFname(e.target.value)} /><br/>
               Last Name<br/>
               <input placeholder="Last Name" className="form-control" defaultValue={lname} 
               onChange={(e) => setLname(e.target.value)}  /><br/>
               Roll No<br/>
               <input placeholder="Roll Number" className="form-control" disabled defaultValue={rnum}/><br/>
               <button onClick={updateData}>Update Details</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UpdateUser;
```

help me i am doing capstone project

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function UpdateUser() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [fname, setFname] = useState("");
    const [lname, setLname] = useState("");
    const [rnum, setRnum] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        // Check if location.state is available to prevent accessing properties of undefined
        if (location.state) {
            setFname(location.state.fname || "");
            setLname(location.state.lname || "");
            setRnum(location.state.rnum || "");
        } else {
            console.log("No state passed to UpdateUser component, redirecting...");
            // Redirect or handle the missing state as needed
            window.location.href = "./"; // Redirect to a default route
        }
    }, [location, location.state]);

    const updateData = async () => {
        console.log(fname, lname);
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/updateUser", {
                method: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    id: location.state?._id, // Optional chaining in case state is undefined
                    fname: fname,
                    lname: lname,
                }),
            });

            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
            window.location.href = "./userDetails";
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to update user details:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="auth-wrapper">
            <div className="auth-inner">
                First Name<br />
                <input
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={fname}
                    onChange={(e) => setFname(e.target.value)}
                /><br />
                Last Name<br />
                <input
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={lname}
                    onChange={(e) => setLname(e.target.value)}
                /><br />
                Roll No<br />
                <input
                    placeholder="Roll Number"
                    className="form-control"
                    disabled
                    value={rnum}
                /><br />
                <button onClick={updateData}>Update Details</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UpdateUser;
```

Comment: userDetails:1 Error handling response: Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws/ws' is invalid.
    at init (chrome-extension://fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/reload.js:22:18)
    at chrome-extension://fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/reload.js:65:13

Comment: location.state.fname is undefined, Please put console.log(location.state.fname) in useEffect and it will print undefined in console, Something wrong in getting data from location and I can't debug that by seeing this component code. Thanks.

Comment: thank you. But still not problem fixed and which code i need to give like nodejs update code or reactjs. Is it problem from endpoint or what‍♂️.

my project is like when user (JWT) login it will navigate to userDetails there will be userUpdate option  will be provide